# Large Table Min/Max

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using SQL 2014 and I am currently trying to return the min and max value of the id column, the id column is a primary key and has a unique, non clustered index.  My table contains 206,923,208 records and this is continuing to grow.  I am also selecting my records based on a create date example code below

```
select min(id) from  tier_post (nolock) 
where created_datetime >= '2016-11-13' and created_datetime <= '2016-11-15'
```

Based on my record selection above I return 651,315 records but to find the min and max of the id its still taking 6+ minutes after this time I stoped the script

Initially I was doing the min and max within the same select statement but this causes the statement to run slower still so I thought I would try and break it up and run it individually.

To confuse matters worse this table is continually getting populated every 5 minutes via a SSIS package so this is likely causing some of the issue when the time of my script runs over this period.

Has anyone else come across issues similar to this and has any ideas how to rectify it?

Thanks

Comment: What indexes are available on the table?

Comment: Hi BishNaboB, there is a unique non clustered index on id and a non unique, non clustered index on created_datetime

Comment: I'd be careful about using NOLOCK, especially when you know for sure that the table is being constantly written to. Not sure that is the issue here, but you should read up on the dangers of NOLOCK. What does the execution plan look like? Which index is it using?

Comment: what is datatype of created_datetime?

Comment: Is it a one time/once in  awhile query, or is it something you need to execute excessively?

Comment: In any case run the min and max together. You don't want to scan all the data twice.

Comment: Do you have partitions by created_datetime  on your table? If not, you probably should, before your table become a dead whale.

Comment: Aside: `created_datetime <= '2016-11-15'` is worrisome. Comparing a `datetime` (assumed) to a `date` involves tacking midnight onto the `date`. If you want to include _all_ times on 11/15 then you would want to use `created_datetime < '2016-11-16'` with less-than rather than less-than-or-equal. And using ISO date constants ("20161115") avoids confusion resulting from changes in culture.

Comment: In answer to the comments and sorry for the delay, in relation to the (NOLOCK) unfortunately I know about the issues with using this and I am trying to get the department out of using this as a default fix for everything.  I will likely be removing as the table is getting written to every 5 mintues, Created_datetime is a datetime datatype, the statement will be getting run once a day and in conjunction with a report so up most 3 times a day.  Thanks for the hint Dudu as there are currently no partitions.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select min(id)
from tier_post (nolock) 
where created_datetime >= '2016-11-13' and created_datetime <= '2016-11-15';
```

You want an index.  I would recommend an index on `tier_post(created_datime, id)`.

Note:  On a table with 206,923,208 rows, it will probably take minutes to create the index.  The entire table needs to be read and that seems to be taking time on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the indexing and partitioning suggested in here, I would suggest that since it is such a large data set, help the query out by not having to convert strings to datetime at runtime by explicit casting. Use something like:

```
declare @start_date datetime, @end_date datetime
set @start_date = '2016-11-13'
set @end_date = '2016-11-15'

select select min(id)
from tier_post (nolock) 
where created_datetime >= @start_date
and created_datetime <= @end_date;
```

Comment: According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), the strings will be converted to `datetime`s (assuming `created_datetime` is, in fact, a `datetime`). The query optimizer will recognize that they are constants and only perform the conversion once.

Answer (score 0):

You mention there's an index on id.

I'm going to guess there's *not* an index on created_datetime. The index on id does you no good if you're not looking up by id.

Create an index on created_datetime. Note that for a table with 200 million records, this may take a significant amount of time.